# Image in UITableViewCell slowly turn to dark near the bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I am developing iOS App with UITableViewCell.

I would like to make an image in a cell slowly turn to dark near the bottom of the image.

I am writing down the following.
However, it does not work well at all.

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

※ I use SDWebImage(https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for asynchronous image downloader.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *cellIdentifer = @"myCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifer forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell==nil){
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifer];
    }

    UIImageView *NewsImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString];
    UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeImage.jpg"];

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = NewsImage.frame;
    gradient.colors = @[(id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor],
                        (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [NewsImage.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

    [NewsImage setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:placeholderImage];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: you are not returning tableviewcell.

Comment: Yes, I've already returned tableviewcell. I added it to above code.

Comment: What is exact problem ? Image not loading ? or just image not turing black at bottom.

Comment: No color change happens. The original image appears in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to check: make sure `imageURLString` it's actually an image. 
Second, change `setImageWithURL` (which has been deprecated) to `sd_setImageWithURL`. Also change `gradient.frame` to `NewsImage.bounds`. If that still doesn't work, try to move the gradient snippet bellow the SDWebImage statement.

Comment: On your third check(change gradient.frame to NewsImage.bounds), I can solve the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is:

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString];
```

What's in "imageURLString"

If you just trying to bring in image file in your project, you can try:

NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"imageFileName" withExtension:@"ext"];

Comment: imageURLString is url(http://...). The original image(but not gradient) appears , so this part is no problem.

Comment: @szakira The original image is the placeholder image ?

Comment: NO. The original image is the image from imageURLString.

Comment: So, if you need new image, where is it set? that's what i meant on my 3rd line in my answer.